# How can I import Facebook contacts into LinkedIn?

Tags: email, facebook, linkedin

Importing into Yahoo mail doesn't work for me since it halts at about 300 contacts out of 1500 (known bug).

Answer (score 2):

Get an account on http://www.gmx.com, import your Facebook contacts. Exporting doesn't work for me (it produces 0-length files), but this workaround did:

- on GMX, go to Contacts
- right click on the Facebook group
- send e-mail to group
- copy all addresses

At this point you can send invitations to this list by pasting it into LinkedIn (Add connections -> Any Email -> Invite by individual email).

If you would like to screen the invites before they are sent, do the following:

- paste the semicolon-separated addresses into a file
- run: sed 's/\;/\n/g' file
- open a GMail account
- switch from Mail to Contacts
- import that file

Now you can import from that GMail account into LinkedIn, which will show you a list with names and pictures that you can choose to remove from the invite list.

Cheers,
redondos

Comment: Someone did their research.

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://rocketconnections.com
It's a web application, you log into Facebook, then to Linkedin and it does all the work for you.